# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?:[\d]+|me$/: Unterminated group

Tags: regex, wordpress

I have generated a min file by grunt and it is giving an error in the new Wordpress version 5.7.

It is showing this error below
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?:[\d]+|me$/: Unterminated group.

When i go to the source file, i got this one `new RegExp(j?"^"+j+"$":d,"i");`

I removed the code and it is working partially. So i need to change this with correct syntax. Please let me know what is the correct syntax instead of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The value of `d` is apparently `(?:[\d]+|me` and is missing a right parenthesis.

Comment: can you write the exact you want to say ?

Comment: I meant `j` not `d`. The value of `j` should be `(?:[\d]+|me)` rather than `(?:[\d]+|me`. You just need to figure out how `j` got that value in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Add `)`, use

```js
/^(?:\d+|me)$/i
//         ^
```

Also, `[\d]` = `\d`. See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/KTVWO6/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    me                       'me'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```